African American woman assassinates Hispanic man in jail cell
What movie is this?
Woman hits a cop car and goes to jail. Later she changes into ninja gear and assassinates a man in the jail cell. She then returns to her jail cell in time to not be thought of as the killer. The police officer on watch was deemed guilty.
It seemed like an extremely modern movie. A friend of mine told me about it but none of us know what movie it is.

This sounds like a particular scene from the movie Colombiana, a rather "modern" (2011) movie starring Zoe Saldana:

A young woman grows up to be a stone-cold assassin after witnessing
  her parents' murder as a child in Bogota. She works for her uncle as a
  hitman by day, but her personal time is spent engaging in vigilante
  murders that she hopes will lead her to her ultimate target - the
  mobster responsible for her parents' death.

And Wikipedia even lists your description as part of the plot summary:

She is assigned to kill the notorious gangster Genarro Rizzo (Affif
  Ben Badra), who is currently in police custody. Implementing an
  elaborate plan, she gets herself arrested while dressed in a disguise.
  She manages to escape her cell with tools she hid in her disguise,
  travel through the ventilation system, successfully kill Rizzo, and
  return to her cell. The next morning she is released.

I think this particular plot section was also featured rather prominently in the movie's trailer.

Kitschy Besson action flick = add to watchlist; Movies directed by a chap named Megaton = add to watchlist; Zoe Saldana = add to watchlist :) (From the IMDb review: "I really like Zoe Saldana, even though her body is a better actress than she is.")

I already thought about it from the moment I saw the title...
